# How to load routes declared in dev subdirectory? (in dev environment)

Tags: symfony, profiler, symfony-3.3, symfony-flex

I'm testing Symfony with Flex. I have a very small application which is working fine (the lucky number generator). I want to add the web_profiler via Flex.

I launch this command:
`composer require web_profiler --dev`

It works fine, cache is succesfully warmed up. But when I check my homepage, an error occured: *The "_wdt" route does not exist.*

I checked the new `config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml` file. It was created by Flex. It contains:

```
web_profiler_wdt:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
    prefix: /_wdt

web_profiler_profiler:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
    prefix: /_profiler
```

It seems to be good. I copy this code and append it to my `config/routes.yaml` . The error disappear. I understood that my yaml files in the `config/routes/dev` subdirectories are not loaded.

Why my files in `/config/routes/dev subdirectory` are not loaded ? Which step did I forget to load my dev config files ?

Here is my `.env` file:

```
# This file is a "template" of which env vars needs to be defined in your configuration or in an .env file
# Set variables here that may be different on each deployment target of the app, e.g. development, staging, production.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=1
APP_SECRET=80b8077a9ccaaf2b5dd3427b512bae42
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

Here is my `config/routes.yaml` file

```
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\GeneratorController::numberAction' }

# Depends on sensio/framework-extra-bundle, doctrine/annotations, and doctrine/cache
#   install with composer req sensio/framework-extra-bundle annot
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

This is the screenshot of the config subdirectories. I think that I respect standards:
[image: This is the screenshot of the config subdirectories]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache was succesfully warmed up, but it is not enough. To works, I have to clear the cache too.

In my composer.json, I added a line for the post update commands:

```
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
      "security:check": "symfony-cmd",
      "cache:clear --no-warmup": "symfony-cmd",
      "cache:warmup": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
```

The line added is this one : `"cache:clear --no-warmup": "symfony-cmd"`

This line is not necessary when installing application, but it is needed during an update.